# listen for changes in a textbox

Tags: jquery, events, textbox, listener

I'm trying to write some code for a personalised products  page on my site. My aim is to have a textbox allowing the user to enter a personal message to go on the product and use jQuery to  determine the price based on the number of characters entered. Then print the price back on screen.

I'm not sure which even listener I should be using. "keyup" seems to stop after the first character entered and "change" only works when the user click off the text box. I would like the code to increase the price as the user types. Any tips on where I'm going wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     $(document).ready(function()  {
        jQuery("#phrase").change( function () {     
                 var length = jQuery("#phrase").length;
                 var price = length * 2.5;


                 jQuery("#price").html(price);
    });

});
</script>
```

jsFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/WVHaT/8/

Comment: and HTML code ? where is it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `jQuery("#phrase").length` gets the amount of ELEMENTS matching the jQuery selector. Rather use `jQuery("#phrase").val().length` to get the amount of characters entered.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#phrase').keyup(function() {
  var length = this.value.length * 2.5;
  $('#price').html(length);
});
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/jameskyburz/WVHaT/

Answer (score 1):

change your code from

```
var length = jQuery("#phrase").length;
```

to

```
var length = jQuery("#phrase").val().length;
```

and call `jQuery("#phrase").keyup`

Answer (score 0):

I would use `keyup`, since it is fired *after* the textbox's value has been updated (in contrast to `keydown` that is fired before the textbox's value is updated) and also *directly after* the key is up (in contrast to the `.change` event which only fires when the input loses focus).

That it does seem to only fire for one key is another problem, which the answer of FarligOpptreden solves!